# Is it possible to run GUI programs without a desktop installed?

Tags: command-line, gedit, chromebook, gksudo, crouton

I'm using [crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) which enables me to run 14.04 on my Chromebook. I opted to *not* install a desktop to save disk space so used the `cli-extra` target when installing:

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -r trusty -t cli-extra -n cli
```

I can now run `sudo enter-chroot` from my Chrome OS shell.

**My question**

Is it possible to launch graphical programs such as gedit? When I use LXDE on another system, I can run `gksudo gedit` to launch the program but this command isn't recognised in this case. Also, running `sudo gedit` results in the message "Cannot open display:".

Answer (score 2):

The Xorg server is what takes care of drawing a graphical environment. When Xorg is launched, it also launches an application with a GUI. When this application exits, so does Xorg (if I recall correctly). In Ubuntu, this application is the Unity desktop environment.

You should be able to install a barebones Xorg server, and use the command line (I think `xinit gedit` should do it) to make it launch the application you want. Alternatively, you can install a lightweight window manager like Openbox. These are typically less user-friendly than full-blown desktop environments like Gnome, Unity and KDE Plasma, but they are also a lot smaller and faster.